# mysql query to get messages(send or receive) for the user

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fetch the records from two tables user_table and message_log table with specified user_id recent messages either sent or received along with sender or receiver user details.

user_table:

**user_id|user_name|user_profile_pic**

message_log:

**msg_id|msg_from_user|msg_to_user|msg_message|msg_datetime**

Result should be:

**user_id|user_name|user_profile_pic|msg_id|msg_from|msg_to|msg_message|msg_datetime**

233 | ravi|/img/img1.png | 90 | 234 | 233 | Hi my message | 2018-01-08 02:02:14

235 | ravi | /img/img1.png | 90 | 235 | 234 | Hi there | 2018-01-05 12:02:28

230 | ravi | /img/img1.png | 90 | 230 | 234 | Bye | 2018-01-05 12:02:28

I tried as below:

```
SELECT tbl_user.user_id,tbl_user.user_name,tbl_user.user_profile_pic, tbl_message_log_temp.* 
FROM tbl_user

LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT s1.* FROM tbl_message_log as s1 LEFT JOIN tbl_message_log AS s2 ON s1.msg_from_user_id = s2.msg_from_user_id AND s1.msg_datetime < s2.msg_datetime WHERE s2.msg_from_user_id IS NULL

    ) as tbl_message_log_temp ON (tbl_user.user_id = tbl_message_log_temp.msg_from_user_id) 
WHERE `user_id` IN (

     SELECT DISTINCT(`msg_to_user_id`) from tbl_message_log WHERE `msg_from_user_id` = 234 ORDER BY `msg_id` DESC)
```

But i am not getting the recent messages.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: I am using MySQL